# What is the meaning of 16:9 aspect ratio in TV or mobile devices?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, resolution, google-tv, television

I'm developing android app for google TV, in the [TV display resolution](https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_android_patterns#Display) section I can't catch what it is saying in this sentence.

> The horizontal resolution is derived from the TV's aspect ratio. Nearly all TVs now use an aspect ratio of 16:9 (16 horizontal pixels for every 9 vertical ones), so the resulting display resolution for a TV set to 1080 is 1920 x 1080. I saw about this concept when you are creating game in the other engine like unity but I did not understand what they are saying.

I've read about aspect ratio when I'm using game engine like unity but these concepts are vague for me. can anyone explain it to me or give me some simple tutorial about these concept?

Comment: This is the key phrase:`16:9 (16 horizontal pixels for every 9 vertical ones)`. I don't see how this could be any clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aspect ratio is simply the ratio of the "width" to the "height" of the screen.  So if a screen is 4 in. in width and has a height of 3 in. then its aspect ratio would be 4:3.  It would also have an aspect ratio of 4:3 if it had a width of 8 in and a height of 6 in. You might be thinking, "Wait, wouldn't it be 8:6?"  Technically you'd be correct, but we like to reduce ratios to their simplest form so as to keep them universal.

1920 and 1080 are both divisible by 120.  1920/120 = 16.  1080/120 = 9.  Thus the aspect ratio is 16:9.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as that, `16 horizontal pixels for every 9 vertical ones`, that means the actual resolution `e.g. 1920x1080` are multiples of 16 and 9. `120*16 x 120*9`.

In the example they want to have vertical resolution of `1080`, so you can sort out the horizontal resolution by the aspect ratio you want to have. `horizontal_resolution = 1080/9 * 16`